# How to get the recursion function to output the number and start with f(0) and get f(n) to count up

Tags: c++

My current output doesn't show the calculations and it counts f(n) down from what the user inputs to f(0). How do I get it to count up starting with the base case f(0) to f(n) and also calculate this recursive case formula f(n) = 2 * f(n-1) -3? This is just twisting my brain for some reason, any help greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int f(int n);

int main (){
    int number;

    cout << "Enter a number greater than or equal to 0: ";
    cin >> number;

    while(number<0){
        cout << "Please enter a valid number!" << endl;
        cout << "Enter a number greater than or equal to 0: ";
        cin >> number;
    }

    f(number);
}

int f(int n){

    //Base Case
    if (n==0){
        cout << "f(" << n << "): " << 5 << endl;      
    }

    //Recursive case
    else{
        cout << "f(" << n << "): " << endl;
        2 * f(n-1)-3;
    }
}
```

An example output that I'm supposed to get with my base case `f(0)=5`, is:

```
f(0): 5,
f(1): 7,
f(2): 11,
f(3): 19,
f(4): 35,
f(5): 67,
f(6): 131,
f(7): 259,
f(8): 515
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not returning anything, which causes a bad output:

```
int f(int n){

    //Base Case
    if (n==0) {
        cout << "f(" << n << "): " << 5 << endl;
        return 5;    
    }

    //Recursive case
    else {
        int temp = 2 * f(n-1)-3;
        cout << "f(" << n << "): " << temp << endl;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

This way, you first get the recursive call back first, outputting lower values as a side effect, and then you output the current new `n` and return its value.

And now your recursive calls are back down instead of up.

Comment: You should explicitly point out that you fixed the count down vs count up by moving the recursive call to *before* the output.

Comment: @MartinBonner true, removed the last part of the answer and added the count down/up part.

Comment: Hey, guys thank you very much, I was just being an idiot. I understand what I was doing wrong now.

Comment: @QMAdams That's the advantage of 40 years experience - I am now *really* good at being an idiot.

Comment: @Martin Bonner Hopefully that will be my fulltime job in a few years, lol